# Invalid ALTER TABLE option ORA-01735

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm looking to add an identity column to my existing table in oracle apex, but I am being given the invalid ALTER TABLE option error. I've been searching through a lot of threads about this error but I couldn't seem to find anything helpful for this particular problem.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_Customer
ADD Customer_ID int Identity(1,1);
```

I'd appreciate a link to any posts that may be useful, thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong syntax. Should be

```
SQL> create table tbl_customer (name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> alter table tbl_customer add customer_id int generated always as identity;

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Besides, you are NOT using MySQL as you got ORA-01735 error (which is related to Oracle).

Comment: Ah my mistake about the mysql tag, thank you, this syntax worked for me. As a side question, do I have to clarify that I want the field to be NOT NULL or the primary key for an identity column?

Comment: Primary key constraint means NOT NULL so - no, you don't have to specify it. Won't harm if you do, though.

Comment: Looks, Like everything is working now, just gotta go through for each table now. Thanks for the help